# command to reboot as non-root user

Tags: debian, power-management, acpi

I am using LXDE on Debian. When logged in LXDE as user, I can click on the `logout` icon in the menu and choose one of the options:

- `shutdown`
- `reboot`
- `logout`
- `suspend`

But when I type `reboot` or `shutdown -r now` in the terminal, that does not work.

How can I shutdown my system as the user from within the terminal? I need a command, which will be executed when my battery is critically low, so that my system can be shut down cleanly.

Comment: you need to add the right to your user to use the command `poweroff` or `shutdown` using visudo.

Comment: Can't the power management software do things like that? It should be running with sufficient privileges already. I know apcupsd can be made to do it, because I use it to do it :)

Comment: When you have physical control over the system (it sits on your desk) and the reset button is within arms length, these security restrictions seem absurd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command run when your computer is running low on battery should be configurable through your desktop environment's GUI. Just open the settings app of whatever you use and look at the power options, you should have something like (this is on Cinnamon):

[image]

To make your user able to run these commands without entering a password, run `sudo visudo` to edit `/etc.sudoers` and add these lines (assuming your user name is `martin`):

```
martin ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
martin ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/reboot
martin ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown
```

You can then run them with no password like so:

```
sudo reboot
```

---

Alternatively, and specifically for `shutdown`, you can add your user to `/etc/shutdown.allow` and then run `shutdown -a` but that one does not work for Debian.

Comment: But you can click on the menu item in your desktop environment, even if you aren't a sudoer. You could trigger the same mechanism from the command line. (D-Bus, but I don't know what message to send.)